# Listening to a newly created model on click?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am creating a model on click and was wondering where is the best place to listen for validation events on the model? I create the model, set the input value on the attribute then create a listener, it doesn't feel right having this listener in the click handler but maybe I'm wrong?

**JS**

```
    buttonClicked: function(event) {
            var input = this.$('.js-input'),
                itemValue = input.val(),
                model = new Item({
                    item: itemValue
                }, {
                    validate: true
                });

        this.listenTo(model, 'invalid', this.onFormError, this);
    }
```

Link to codepen http://codepen.io/styler/pen/rearYp

Comment: You don't seem to be doing anything with the `model` reference. As alex noted, this depends on what you're doing with it. Are you passing it to a new view? are you adding it to a collection..? Since you mentioned *to-do app* in comments, you must be having a collection or something? please edit the question and add more info.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you do with the model. If you want to display it in a new view, the validation should be inside the initialize of the new view.

```
var view= Backbone.View.extend({
   model:Item,
   initialize: function (model, options) {
     this.listenTo(this.model, 'invalid', this.onFormError, this);
   },
   ......
}
```

If you use it locally you can let it on the click handler.

Try this ...............

```
var view= Backbone.View.extend({
    model:Item,
    initialize: function (model, options) {
        this.model= new Item();
        this.listenTo(this.model, 'invalid', this.onFormError, this);
        this.render();
    },
    buttonClicked: function(event) {
        var input = this.$('.js-input'),
        itemValue = input.val(),
        this.model.set('item', itemValue);
        if(!this.model.isValid(true)){
              return;
        }
    }
    ......
}
```

Comment: The problem with that is a model doesn't exist until a user clicks submit and the model is created so I can't listen for this.model in initialise or I get an error if you know what I mean?

Comment: I think I understand what you want to do. Correct me if I'm wrong: You want to have a model which validate a form on submit.

If so on current view initialize you should create an empty Model, link the validation to it, and on render linked it to the template. On submit set the new values and call validate. (see edited code)

If not let me know your user story.

Comment: Yeah so the user will be submitting a new item model each time, I can't instantiate the model in initialize as the model has to be new each time the submission happens - think a todo list - submit a todo, make sure the input isn't empty by validation